# website added to home screen doesn't refresh (android chrome)

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, web-applications, page-refresh

I created a website with the possibility to be added to the homescreen. the problem is that if the chrome tab is still running in the background and i open it again, it opens the website without refreshing it.

is it possible to force refresh an added to homescreen website? something to put in `head`maybe?

iOS behaves correctly (it always refresh)

i have this in `head`:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

thanks!

Comment: Same "issue" here—I use scare quotes because I like that it doesn't always refresh, but I wish there were a way to manually refresh it. As it is, it would seem there is no way to force a refresh, and the phone is sometimes left running a stale version of the app.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. on android chrome you can swipe from up to down on the top edge of the screen to start a refresh. Not sure on iOS though. I had this problem on an angular project and it was solved, but I'm not sure how my friend did it. you can check the repo here: https://github.com/vlrprbttst/partita-domani-a-roma

Comment: Not talking about Chrome though, but rather the added-to-homescreen web apps? Is this also the case for these?

Comment: @valerio0999 That doesn't seem to work with certain meta tags on the page.  I'm not sure which ones, but at one point it stopped working for me when I added certain tags and styling to prevent the page from scrolling or zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot yet comment on your question.

But what kind of iOS device are you using? Because it could very well be due to the limited ram that most iOS devices have and sometimes the internal taskkiller is the reason for Chrome refreshing so often. Many users experience that when you leave Chrome and come back to it, that the pages reload: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/E8cIWIsOn9s/ZAS1ydPed90J

I hope that helps.